# Generic stored procedure using Dapper

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Consider this `C#` code:

```
var _tableName = "[Users]";
var query = $"Select * From {_tableName} Where [Id] = @Id;";
```

This query is reausable, i can use it with any table in my project.

I can use stored procedure to reproduce this select:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSomething

@Id INT

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Something WHERE Id= @Id;
END
```

and call it from `Dapper`:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@Id", id);

using var connection = _databaseConnection.GetOpenConnection();

return await connection.QueryFirstAsync<SmthDto>("GetSomething", parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

But as you can see, from this procedure im calling table `Something`.

How to make `Stored Procedure` reusable/generic to call any table like `var query` is working?

Comment: add another parameter for the table name.

Comment: All in, your approach saves you approximately nothing and starts down the road of opening your whole app up to a world of hacking possibilities. I hope you don't [work for vtech](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vtech+hack&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: Could you explain how that approuch can be SQL Injected and how to do IT properly?

Answer (score 2):

You can create dynamic query in stored procedure, in which you can pass table name as parameter and then call it from dapper by passing tablename and id parameter.

```
-- EXEC GetSomething 'Something',2
Create PROCEDURE GetSomething
@tableName as nvarchar(150),
@Id as INT
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @rawQuery nvarchar(250);
    SET @rawQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE Id='+ Cast(@Id as nvarchar); 
    EXECUTE sp_executesql  @rawQuery
END
```

Comment: -1 from me: advocating an approach that is massively susceptible to SQL Injection hacking. If you're going to recommend this, recommend a parameterized dynamic SQL

Comment: Agree with @CaiusJard on this one. If the table name 'Something' is passed in unprotected, so can 'Something where 1 = 2; Drop Something; Select *'. If you can't see what's wrong with that paste it into a query window and have a good look, but don't run it.
Second, creating and deleting SPs every query is hugely inefficient. Executing raw SQL would allow SQL Server to do less and recognise a reusable query plan.

Comment: (And quotename if you're passing identifiers)